# Remove section from TOC while keeping its own page header

Tags: table-of-contents

This is my first question submission to StackExchange, so please bear with me.

I have a thesis using the `scrartcl` class and `classicthesis` package. I would like for my Abstract to exist on its own page, with its own page header in the top right corner that says "Abstract" next to the page number, just like for every other section. However, I neither want the Abstract to have a section number, nor do I want it to show up in my Table of Contents. I searched many times for an answer to this specific question, and while I can find ways to remove it from the ToC, or to remove its section number, or to place it on its own page with its own page header, I cannot find a way to do all three simultaneously. It's also important for the section following the Abstract, the Introduction, to be the first section with a section number of 1.

In the code below, note that the output shows the page header as "Contents" for the page(s) where the Abstract sits, and I'd like for it to say "Abstract" instead, without giving the Abstract a section number or place in the ToC.

```
\documentclass[
    headinclude,footinclude, % Extra spacing for the header and footer
    ]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[
nochapters, % Turn off chapters since this is an article        
]{classicthesis} % The layout is based on the Classic Thesis style

\usepackage{lipsum} % Used for inserting dummy 'Lorem ipsum' text into the template

\title{Title} % The article title

\begin{document}
\maketitle % Print the title/author/date block
\tableofcontents % Print the table of contents
\newpage
\section*{Abstract} % starred section doesn't get the correct header
%\section{Abstract} % unstarred section gets the correct header

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your example doesn't compile as we don't have structure.tex. Try to make a small but complete example.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Since it appears most of your document doesn't affect the symptom, I've taken the liberty of greatly minimizing your example document, which should make it easier for others to find a solution.

Comment: @MikeRenfro When I compile the minimized version provided, I no longer see any page header on the Abstract's page (I don't see "Contents"; I just see nothing), whether I use `\section*{Abstract}` or `\section{Abstract}`. The fact that I want the word in the top right corner of the page to say "Abstract", rather than "List of Figures" or anything else, is a key part of the issue I'm facing.

Comment: At least on my system (TeX Live 2016), I get the behavior described. If you see something different, what TeX distribution are you using, and what's the least number of lines you can add back to cause the problem?

Comment: @MikeRenfro Ah, yep. I had downloaded mactex-2016 this morning but had forgotten to run the installer. I'm seeing the same thing you are now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
\section*{Abstract} % starred section doesn't get the correct header
\markright{\spacedlowsmallcaps{Abstract}}% set the header
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[
    headinclude,footinclude, % Extra spacing for the header and footer
    ]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[
nochapters, % Turn off chapters since this is an article        
]{classicthesis} % The layout is based on the Classic Thesis style
\usepackage{lipsum} % Used for inserting dummy 'Lorem ipsum' text into the template
\title{Title} % The article title
\begin{document}
\maketitle % Print the title/author/date block
\tableofcontents % Print the table of contents
\newpage
\section*{Abstract} % starred section doesn't get the correct header
\markright{\spacedlowsmallcaps{Abstract}}% set the header
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

---

Note that `classicthesis` breaks many KOMA-Script features. Without `classicthesis` I would use the class option `headings=optiontoheadandtoc` and then `\addsec[tocentry={}]{Abstract}`:

```
\documentclass[
    headinclude,footinclude,
    headings=optiontoheadandtoc
    ]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{Title}
\pagestyle{headings}% set the page style
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\addsec[tocentry={}]{Abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Beautiful! Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Just to be sure, in the second part you speak about `cleanthesis` while the rest of the question is about `classicthesis`. Mixup?

Comment: Thanks, I would leave another upvote, but i can upvote only once.